# How create new object in scope and have view's method calls use the new object?

Tags: angularjs

I have a view like this:

```
<span ng-if="myobject == null" ng-init="createNewObj()"></span>
<div>checkIsNull(myobject)</div>
```

The method is:

```
$scope.createNewObject = function() { $scope.myobject = { name: "test"; } };
```

But when it runs, it always has `myobject` as null in the `checkIsNull` method. How do I create that object in the scope and have it used in the later parts?

Comment: Why not create the object in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, i wouldnt use ng-if or ng-init for that. i would handle that in the controller. like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <script>
 angular.module('app', [])
   .controller('myController', function($scope) {
     $scope.createNewObject = function() {
       $scope.myobject = { name: "test" };
     };
     function activate() {
       if(!$scope.myobject) {
          $scope.createNewObject();
       }
     }
     activate();

   });

 </script>
  <body ng-app="app" >
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <span>{{myobject.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps!